# How to Insert a datetime in the future in PHP/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

I have a database table with a datetime column. Everything works fine if a make an Insert using the current date :

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('field1', now(), 'field2');
```

But it returns NULL when I try to insert a date in the future. I do this :

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('field1', '2011-07-01 00:00:00', 'field2');
```

What's wrong with this query ??

nb. It works fine when I insert the current date, and then make an update using DATE_ADD()  But it's complicated, there's nothing easier to do this ??

thanks !

Comment: Weird, looks okay to me. Are you running that exact query manually in a tool like phpMyAdmin and it gets set to `NULL`? Are you 10000% sure?

Comment: You're right Pekka, it works. I found out why doing a simple query (
`INSERT INTO table (date_field) values('2011-07-01 00:00:00')`).
Doing so I noticed that one column was missing before the date (this table has more than 30 columns)... My bad, sorry :/

Ok so in the end a basic INSERT like '2010-01-00 00:00:00' works fine on a datetime. I was starting to think there's something special to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad :/

I forgot a column before in my sql query, that's why it returned NULL...

In the end a basic INSERT like '2014-01-00 00:00:00' works fine on a datetime (even if you don't put the hh:mm:ss).

Answer (score 4):

[Take a look at this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

The only problem you really have is that string you want insert to date field is not parsed to string. functions like now(), and other date time returns date type and, as you've written there is no problem with that.
Hint:  "If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning"

Comment: thanks for the link but it still returns _NULL_ when I do this : 
`INSERT INTO table VALUES ( 'field1', STR_TO_DATE('2011-07-01','%Y-%m-%d'), 'field2' )`

Any ideas ?

Comment: When I launch the query below it says my field can't be empty...
`INSERT INTO table (date_field) values(STR_TO_DATE('2011-07-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'))`
It seems like my 'date' doesn't match the pattern, but it does.

Comment: This isn't necessary. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is valid syntax for a date field and doesn't need conversion

Answer (score 0):

Use this

INSERT INTO table VALUES ('field1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'field2');